# Converting flat csv to db format in SQL

Tags: sql, database, csv, hana

I have a csv file in a following format that I can import into SAP HANA DB:

```
employee_id; salary delta 1.1.2016 - 30.6.2016; salary delta 1.7.2016 - 21.12.2016; personal_evaluation 1.1.2016 - 30.6.2016; personal_evaluation 1.7.2016 - 21.12.2016
ID1234;0.05;0.1;0;0.2  
ID32145;0;0.2;0;0
```

Please, how can I convert this in sql to a table that looks like the following?

```
employee_id, start_date, end_date, salary_delta; personal_evaluation_delta
```

I have no idea how to approach this. I can use any standard tool, however I would prefer a solution in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You have a strange format of source csv file. I'm pretty sure that this csv was created manualy. If it was created automatically by some application then it will have more harmonic format.
First of all, you should create a readadble csv file, e.g.:

```
employee_id,start_date,end_date,salary_delta,personal_evaluation_delta
ID244,2010-05-30,2018-01-31,100.50,4.56
ID314,2012-06-11,,40.41,14.54
ID314,2008-02-02,2017-03-28,100.50,5.76
ID388,2016-04-18,2019-01-31,200.78,1.89
ID529,2007-06-23,,300.50,0.36
```

Then you can import it with HANA sql if csv file is on file share that available for HANA database and in HANA configuration csv import is allowed. But it is a complex way I think.

The other way is read read this csv with an excel and create a formula in new column that will concatenate  all values in insert statement. E.g.:

```
="INSERT into ""schema"".""Table"" ( … comma_separated_columns_List) values('" & A2 & "','" & TEXT(B2,"yyyy/MM/dd") & "', …. Etc …)"
```

Assuming here that A2, B2 are Excels columns names that used in formulas as Excel usually does